# SQL sum() not adding up correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Temp table and Insert statement:

```
declare @ClaimNumbers table (ClaimId Id_t, ClaimNumber RefNumber_t, AmtPaid Money_t, RecordStatus Code_t null, Amount Money_t null, ProcessingStatus code_t null)
                        insert into @ClaimNumbers 
                                (
                                    ClaimNumber,
                                    ClaimId,
                                    AmtPaid, 
                                    RecordStatus, 
                                    Amount,
                                    ProcessingStatus
                                ) 
                            select 
                                    E.ReferenceNumber,
                                    E.ClaimId,
                                    sum(E.AmtPaid), 
                                    CBR.RecordStatus, 
                                    sum(CBR.Amount),
                                    C.ProcessingStatus
                               from EDIXacts E 
                          left join ClaimBillingRecords CBR 
                                 on CBR.ClaimId = E.ClaimId
                                and CBR.BillingEntityMapId in (select BillingEntityMapId from BillingEntityMap where BillingEntityId = 255) --@BillingEntityId)
                                and CBR.RecordStatus = 'POS'
                          left join Claims C on C.ClaimId = E.ClaimId
                              where E.CheckId = 1747 --@CheckId
                                and XactType = 'RMT'
                                and XactStatus in ('NRM','SLM')
                          group by E.ReferenceNumber,
                                    E.ClaimId,
                                    CBR.RecordStatus, 
                                    C.ProcessingStatus
```

Given example data:

```
ClaimBillingRecords
ClaimId,RecordStatus,Amount
3807,'POS',-100
3807,'POS',120


EDIXacts
XactType,XactStatus,CheckId,AmtPaid
'RMT','NRM',1747,-100
'RMT','SLM',1747,120
```

I am expecting the Amount to be $20 and the AmtPaid to be $20, however I am getting Amount: $40 and AmtPaid: $40.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the aggregate function?

Comment: Please share table structures of EDIXacts , ClaimBillingRecords  and Claims . There is no ReferenceNumber column in your provided EDIXacts table and claimid is missing

Comment: Apparently someone went crazy with user-defined types - that's not a good sign IMO. And you started writing in a good pattern but blew it when you did not qualify the columns in the where clause - better formatting would highlight the important bits of the query and encourage others to help. If you want to know why your query is not producing the correct amounts, replace the sums with just the column and remove the group by clause. You can't debug things when you don't know what values and which rows are being summed.

Comment: I'll guess you need to join **independently** to your 2 outer joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

Without having complete table structures with valid sample data it's hard to tell what's wrong. My guess is your rows are being multiplied through joining. Please check below select query to check  the data first then use group by to sum those.

```
declare @ClaimNumbers table (ClaimId Id_t, ClaimNumber RefNumber_t, AmtPaid Money_t, RecordStatus Code_t null, Amount Money_t null, ProcessingStatus code_t null)
                        insert into @ClaimNumbers 
                                (
                                    ClaimNumber,
                                    ClaimId,
                                    AmtPaid, 
                                    RecordStatus, 
                                    Amount,
                                    ProcessingStatus
                                ) 
                            select 
                                    E.ReferenceNumber,
                                    E.ClaimId,
                                    sum(E.AmtPaid), 
                                    CBR.RecordStatus, 
                                    sum(CBR.Amount),
                                    C.ProcessingStatus
                               from EDIXacts E 
                          left join ClaimBillingRecords CBR 
                                 on CBR.ClaimId = E.ClaimId
                                and CBR.BillingEntityMapId in (select BillingEntityMapId from BillingEntityMap where BillingEntityId = 255) --@BillingEntityId)
                                and CBR.RecordStatus = 'POS'
                          left join Claims C on C.ClaimId = E.ClaimId
                              where E.CheckId = 1747 --@CheckId
                                and XactType = 'RMT'
                                and XactStatus in ('NRM','SLM')
```

Hope you will get the idea why Amount and AmountPaid column is having double the expected amount.